# write different value on temp file every load

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I create a temp file by php the code is :

```
$filename = tempnam('/tmp', 'cre');
$fp = fopen($filename, 'w');
fwrite($fp, 'store temporary data in a file');
fclose($fp);
unlink($filename);
```

and include this file by :

```
$temp_file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), '');
echo $temp_file;
```

Now how can I write a rendom number on it for every user?
And can I call this file from another page ?
Like: a user come my site now it generated with a number code, I say user to go `code.php` with new tab here i call the tamp file by

```
$temp_file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), '');
echo $temp_file;
```

is it possible ?

Comment: why do you need this? if you want a per-user random number, why can't you just use a session and have `$_SESSION['random_number'] = rand();`?

Comment: You're deleting the file at the end of the first code.